# Is there a way to stop reactjs status page from showing

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I am building an ecommerce with mern stack

When I make request from react to node and it fails it show the status code with error on the page.

is there a way to prevent this from happening

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEwjW.png)

React code

```
  export const createCategories = async(name, token) => {
        return await axios.post(
            `${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_APP_URL}/api/category`,
            name,
            {
                headers: {
                    'x-header-token' : token
                }
            }
        )
    }
const handleSubmit = async(e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setLoading(true)

    try{
        createCategories(category, localStorage.getItem('token'))
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res)
            setLoading(false)
            setCompleted(true)
            setCreateCategory(res.data)
        });
        
       
    }catch(err){
        setError(true)
        setErrorMsg({
            "msg": err.response.data
        })
    }
}
```

nodejs code

```
try{
            const {name} = req.body;
            const category = await new Category({ name, slug: slugify(name)}).save();
            res.json({'msg': "Category Created"})

        }catch(err){
            res.status(400).send("Create Category Failed...")
            console.log(err)
        }
```

Comment: You need to handle exceptions. https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/07/26/error-handling-in-react-16.html

Comment: @dilshan Thanks for the reply. I have updated my question. I tried to try/catch but I am getting the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use `catch` block

```
createCategories(name,token).then(res => {
    // if success in response 
}).catch(error => {
    // if error in response 
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have updated my question. I tried to try/catch but I am getting the same problem

Comment: you no need of outer try-catch in your code try with my approach